# Order by two fields and possibly NULL values, in chronological order

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Three fields:

```
Activity (varchar), Arrival (time), Departure (time)
```

I am attempting to produce output table like this:

```
Activity                    Arrival        Departure
Travel to Hotel             9:00           -
Depart Hotel for Big Ben    -              10:00
Sight-seeing Big Ben        12:00          13:00
```

the `-` indicate a `NULL` value in my table.

I am currently ordering in my query like this:

`ISNULL(Activity.arrival), Activity.arrival ASC`

which works great when an arrival date is supplied. When `arrival` is `null`,  I end up with a table like this

```
Activity                       Arrival        Departure
Travel to Hotel                9:00           -
Sight-seeing Big Ben           12:00          13:00 // problem!
Depart Hotel for Big Ben       -              10:00 // should be up one.
```

I am not sure if I can achieve this using pure SQL.

The query being peformed is:

```
SELECT `id`, `activity`, `arrival`, `departure` FROM `activities` ORDER BY ISNULL(`arrival`) ASC, `arrival` ASC
```

And I'm just outputting:

```
foreach($r as $k) {
    echo $k['activity'] . ' ' . $k['arrival'] . ' ' . $k['departure'];
}
```

whether I need to manipulate this at output or not?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: The way to solve these type of issues is by introducing a `sortorder` column, The activities should have a sort order of the order they are happening,

Comment: that's a good point actually and would probably be easier to understand at a glance, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()` Which will return the first non-null value.

`ORDER BY COALESCE(Activity.arrival, Activity.departure)`

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use:-

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(Activity.arrival, Activity.departure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not try, but I think something like this would work:

```
SELECT `id`, `activity`, `arrival`, `departure`
FROM `activities` 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN `arrival` IS NULL THEN `departure` END ASC,
    `departure` ASC
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem essentially comes from some ambiguity about how you want these sorted. If you can specify the rule that you want for sorting, it becomes easy to code that rule in SQL.

For example, I might guess that if the arrival is not null, sort by arrival. If the arrival is not null, use the departure time, so the departure precedes the next arrival time. Does that work for you?

If that's the case, the solution becomes evident:

```
order by coalesce(arrival, departure)
```

meaning if arrival is null, use departure instead.